# How to call base class overloaded func using derived class instance,

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to understand if the derived class has overloaded base class func, (base class has int parameter and der class has double parameter) when i created der class instance and call func name with correct parameters, only der func is called?? Can someone help me in this .. Is there a way at line 28 of code (dd.f(d1);) , I can get base class func call.

Here is the code.

```
using namespace std;

class base {

    public :

        virtual void f (int i);

};

class der : public base{

    public:

        void f ( double d);

};

void base::f(int i){

    cout << "Base::f \n";

}

void der::f(double d){

    cout <<"Der::f \n";

}

int main(){

    der dd;

    int i =99;

    double d1 = 3232.232;

    dd.f(i); // why this calls der class func???

    dd.f(d1);

    base *ptr = new der();

    ptr->f(i);

    dynamic_cast<der *>(ptr)->f(d1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler will not search for overloads in multiple scopes. It finds the first version of "f(...)" in the class hierarchy and stops there. It will then search that class and only that class for overloads. It finds der::f(double) as an overload with an implicit cast from int to double and uses it. You can put "using base::f;" inside "der" to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare function in derived class with same name as in base class, function in base class is hided.

### Solution

```
`use base::f`

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {     
public :
    virtual void f (int i); 
};

class der : public base{
public:
    using base::f;
    void f ( double d);
};

void base::f(int i){
    cout << "Base::f \n";
}

void der::f(double d){
    cout <<"Der::f \n";
}

int main(){
    der dd;
    int i =99;     
    dd.f(i); // Base::f

    return 0;
}
```

### Reasoning

```
class Base {
    virtual void store(long l){
        //both int and long could be processed
    }
}
```

You create Derived class

```
class Derived {
    virtual void store(long l) {
        //store another way.
    }
}

and call it like 

Derived d;
d.store(1);
```

Then somebody think "I could store ints more quickly!" and create

```
Base::store(int)
```

and you fail if there's no hiding like this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ programmer, but I'm fairly certain that the language identifies the function/method being called by the parameters being passed to it, as well as the name. f(int) is different than f(double). Do some searching on polymorphism

Comment: From your explanation the method of base class should be called. And question is why it isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

*why this calls der class func???*

Because the compiler chooses functions by signatures only between those which are declared in the same class. For example if you had something like this:

```
class der : public base{

public:
    void f ( double d);
    void f (int i ){cout << "f(int)" <<endl;}
};
```

Calling your `dd.f(i);` would bring you to the output `f(int)`.

Since your `der` class has a function `f()` although the calling parameters don't match, the compiler doesn't have a need to go to `base` class, it just converts your `int` to `double`

In order to call explicitly `f()` from `base` class you can do it like this: `dd.base::f(i);`

Comment: "the compiler doesn't have a need to go to base class" - It's slightly worse than this. The compiler *will not* go to the base class, even if it has a need to. Try changing the "f(int)" to a "f(std::string)" and then call it as "der.f(std::string())" instead of "der.f(i)". It will not compile because it can't convert std::string to double. This program only compiles because C++ will convert int to double automatically.

Comment: @JoshG79 yes, the compiler will try to find an apropriate function in the base class only if there aren't any (with the same name) in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, was aware of scope resolution operator earlier. but didnt think of it :)

Comment: Yes, even I tried calling func f with string parameter and it failed even if the func was properly declared in base class. But as RiaD suggested adding "using base::f" in der class even this issue was resolved. I was not aware if you overload funcs in der class, then base class func will be hidden. Something  nice to learn. Thanks to you all for sharing information and getting involved in discussion. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

the following is called overriding

```
class baseClass
{
public:
    virtual void DoIt()
    {//.........
    }
}
class child : public baseClass
{
    void DoIt()
    {
        baseClass::DoIt();
    }
}
```

in microsoft visual C++
you can use **_*super*** instead of base class name **_super::DoIt()**

what you are doing is not overriding it is another method with different signature if there are problems just use in the public body of your class **using base::confusingMethod;** like the following.

```
class base
{
public:
    base(){}
    virtual void Job(int x)
    {
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
    }
};
class son : public base
{
public:
    using base::Job;
    son(){}
    virtual void Job(float x)
    {
        cout<<"Son"<<endl;
    }
};
```